# I keep getting list index out of range when there is more elements left, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am using this to delete the non alphabetical characters from a list

```
alphabet = -1
int(alphabet)
while alphabet != howlong:
    alphabet = alphabet + 1
    print alphabet
    if ldata[alphabet] == "a":
        print "a" 
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "b":
        print "b"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "c":
        print "c"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "d":
        print "d"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "e":
        print "e"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "f":
        print "f"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "g":
        print "g"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "h":
        print "h"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "i":
        print "i"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "j":
        print "j"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "k":
        print "k"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "l":
        print "l"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "m":
        print "m"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "n":
        print "n"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "o":
        print "o"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "p":
        print "p"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "q":
        print "q"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "r":
        print "r"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "s":
        print "s"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "t":
        print "t"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "u":
        print "u"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "v":
        print "v"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "w":
        print "w"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "x":
        print "x"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "y":
        print "y"
    elif ldata[alphabet] == "z":
        print "z"
    else:
        #deletes non letter and all of the same things from the list
        z = ldata[alphabet]
        ldata = [x for x in ldata if x != z]
```

It gets up to the 57742 element then says list index out of range. I counted the list and it gets above that. Also that is not pythons maximum possible number of elements in the list. I am very confused and was wondering if there was anything I could have missed. Please help this is due on monday :(. If there is a more simple way to do this also I would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: You can save yourself 50 lines of code by writing `if "a" <= ldata[alphabet] <= "z": print(ldata[alphabet])`. `int(alphabet)` is doing exactly nothing, you can remove that line as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

The error is coming from the fact that you are deleting from the list as you iterate through it. The optimum way to correct this would be as follows:

```
new_list = [char for char in ldata if "a" <= char <= "z"]
```

---

*This method can be corrected by decrementing `howlong` every time you remove an item.*
You could do the following, which should avoid the list index out of range problem:

```
for char in ldata:
    if "a" <= char <= "z": 
        print(char)
```

By using this for-each style loop, you will iterate through every single entry in the list. This will ensure you get to every item without the possibility of your index going out of bounds.

---

Full credit to @DYZ's suggestion to use `if "a" <= ldata[alphabet] <= "z": print(ldata[alphabet])` for the inner part of the for loop!

Comment: How could I remove the non alphabetical charecters?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include this - I think this would be the most efficient, and shorten your current code by a lot.

Comment: @bobjoe Did this work for what you were trying to do?

Comment: Cool! Please do upvote/mark the answer as correct (the green tick) if it helped you. Or if I can modify the answer to make it more appropriate let me know!